# Balanced subsets of $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

This is an exercise from the book "An Introduction to Banach Space Theory" by Megginson:

> Identify all of the balanced subsets of $\mathbb C$. Do the same for $\mathbb R^2$.

For the first part I think the balanced subsets are $\emptyset, \mathbb C$ and the bounded subsets of $\mathbb C$ since if $\emptyset\neq A\subset \mathbb C$ is a balanced set that is not bounded then for any $x\in C$ there is $y\in A$ such that $|y|\geq |x|$ so $x=\frac xyy\in A$.

However I don't know how to deal with $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: I don't think I've heard of balanced subsets. What are they?

Comment: The subset of $\mathbb C$ being bounded is not enough. Consider $\{ z = x + iy \in \mathbb C \mid 0 \leq x \leq 1, y = 0 \}$. Is it bounded? Is it balanced?

Comment: @Arthur: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_set

Comment: @md2perpe thanks. $\{ z = x + iy \in \mathbb C \mid 0 \leq x \leq 1, y = 0 \}$ is bounded but not balanced. By the link you provided the balanced subsets are $\emptyset,\mathbb C$ and the open and closed balls centered at zero. How can I proof this? what's wrong with my attempt?

Comment: In your attempt you proved that, if $A$ is unbounded and balanced, then $A=\Bbb C$ (true). You did not prove that all bounded sets are balanced (false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The balanced subsets of $\Bbb C$ are exactly $\emptyset$, $\Bbb C$ and the (open and closed) disks centered in $0$. This is because of these three facts:

   - a balanced set is the union of the balanced evelopes of its elements
   - the balanced envelope of a point $z\in\Bbb C$ is the closed disk $\overline {\Delta}(0,\lvert z\rvert)$
   - for a set $S\subseteq \Bbb [0,\infty)$, $\bigcup\limits_{s\in S}\overline{\Delta}(0, s)=\begin{cases}\emptyset&\text{if }S=\emptyset\\ \overline\Delta(0,\sup S)&\text{if }\sup S\in S\\ \Delta(0,\sup S)&\text{if }\sup S\notin S\wedge \sup S\ne\infty\\\Bbb C&\text{if }\sup S=\infty\end{cases}$
2. The balanced subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ are exactly the empty set and the subsets wich are symmetrical star-domains in $0$. I.e., such that $C=-C$ and the closed segment joining any point of $C$ to $0$ is contained in $C$. This can be directly verified from the definitions.